# d3js: Creating a collapsible table & issues with nested data

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am working on creating a collapsible table within d3js and have been having an issue with the nested nature of the data structure that I am working with.  The data is organized as such:

```
var source = [
{name: William, age: 40, children: [{name: Billy, age: 10},{name:Charles, age: 12}]},
{name: Nancy, age: 35, children: [{name: Sally, age:8}]}
]
```

When I first create the table, I move the `children` arrays over into a `_children` object within each respective parent like so:

```
tableData.forEach(function(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
});
```

Using d3js' typical data inputs I can populate a row and coordinates for each parent in the table.

```
source.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = x0;
    d.y = y0;
    var parentX = x0,
      parentY = y0;
    y0 += barHeight + padding;
    if (d.children) {
      d.children.forEach(function(data) {
        data.x = x0;
        data.y = y0;
        data.parentX = parentX;
        data.parentY = parentY;
        y0 += barHeight + padding;
        shownChildren.push(data);
      })
    }
  });
```

I utilize the usual data selection methods:

```
var tableRow = tableSvg.selectAll('.tableRow')
  .data(source);

var rowEnter = tableRow.enter()
  .append("g")
  .classed("tableRow", true)
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
  });
```

As well as placing the rectangles that represent each row:

```
var rowRect = rowEnter.append("rect")
  .attr("height", barHeight)
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click);

var rowText = rowEnter.append("text")
  .attr("dy", 15)
  .attr("dx", 5.5)
  .text(function(d) {
    if (d.name.length > 70) {
      return d.name.substring(0, 67) + "...";
    } else {
      return d.name;
    }
  })
  .on("click", click);
```

Upon clicking a row, the rows move to make space for the addition children rows, the and `_children` array is moved back over into `children` where the above code assigns a location to each child where they are then displayed:

```
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  updateTable(source);
}
```

However, the an issue appears when I create the rows for each child using the exact same manner as for the parents above.  My current implementation builds an array, `shownChildren` (as seen in the third code block) and populates the gaps in the table with the children.  Initially the implementation seemed to work fine, however as you click on the rows, each child row changes position.

I have no guesses as to what is currently causing the problem.

Here is a rundown of the code as I have it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jallison/2d5rhmo1/7/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that I was having was that I was rebuilding the `shownChildren` array each time with a varying number of children.  I fixed the issue by adding all of the `children` and `_children` to the `shownChildren` array (always in the same order!) and hiding each of the `_children` behind their respective parents.

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jallison/2d5rhmo1/17/)